# How to disable the select element in Materialize CSS with VUE?

Tags: vuejs2, materialize

Goodnight.

Working with VUE and MaterializeCSS I'm having problems using  since I need to list a number of options from an array of objects filled in from an Ajax request but apparently VUE is hiding the information by creating a new  under the main one.

Then I would like to know if anyone knows how to deactivate an element of the Materilizecss framework? In this case . Thank you.

Comment: request your selection object by axios,  and use a vue variable to save this.

Comment: Of course, but that is not the problem. Here the problem is with the select element of materilizecss

Answer (score 0):

If someone works for you:

Add the **browser-default** class to the  but indicate in the **display: block** style because for some reason it hides it.

```
                  <select class="browser-default" style="display:block"  v-model="category_id">
                    <option v-for="category in arrayCategories" :key="category.id" :value="category.id" v-text="category.name"></option>
                  </select>
```

Greetings.